# I'm trying to instal ruby on rails but it tells me I haven't installed gem byebug 11.0.1 but I have it installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on a Windows 7 machine. I followed the instructions at http://installrails.com/.  I tried to run server and it said to run `bundle install` to install missing `turbolinks` gem. I could not find `gem 'turbolinks <~> 5> x86 -mingw32'` in any of the gem sources listed on your gemfile or available on this machine

I of course tried bundle install here's the result:
[administrative powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwTKX.png)

Note that I had to install newer version of Ruby and then do `gem install byebug` to get to this point but it's weird to me because it says

> be sure `gem install byebug succeeds`.

It succeeds but it still won't work :(. Any advice?

EDIT: After trying gem install bundler and another bundle install i now get  your ruby version is 2.5.5 but your gemfile specified is 2.2.6? anyone got a work around for this ?

Comment: Havn't used windows in years so can't help there but Windows is not the best environment for Rails (might be better now but used to have speed and compatibility issues). Mac or linux is much better. If you have enough resources on your windows machine run a VM with linux on it - will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: any ideas on a link to find goood vm software?

Comment: [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org) You can then run the desktop edition of your favourite linux flavour (I like Ubuntu) so that it has a browser and you can use a gui text editor, otherwise you can run server version and redirect browser output to your windows host (I prefer first choice)

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote ruby version is 2.5.5 but your gemfile specified is 2.2.6

Go to your Gemfile and delete the ruby line. 
After that you can normally run the bundle install command

And maybe the other problems: install with the new ruby version (2.5.5) the newest rails gem and after that try to install byebug and turbolink.